# Am I getting this right about equations, functions and logic?

Tags: functions, logic, propositional-calculus

When I square the equation $ x=2 $ I get the equation $ x^2=4 $
and I would write
$$
x=2 \Rightarrow x^2=4.
$$
This implication is true for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$. In other words, the sentence
$$\forall x \in \mathbb R: (x=2 \Rightarrow x^2=4)$$
is true. Of course I could also think of this predicate
$$
x^2=4 \Rightarrow x=2 ,
$$
let's call it $A(x)$. There are numbers which turn $A(x)$ into a true sentence but also numbers which turn $A(x)$ into a false sentence, for example $A(-2)$ is a false sentence . So the sentence
$$\forall x \in \mathbb R: (x^2=4 \Rightarrow x=2)$$
is false.

The squaring of the equation $ x=2 $ is actually me using the function $h:t\mapsto t^2$ on both sides of $x=2$. And I know that $x=2 \Rightarrow x^2=4$ is true for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$ because $t_1=t_2 \Rightarrow f(t_1)=f(t_2)$ is true for all $t_1$ and $t_2$.

This

$$t_1=t_2 \Rightarrow f(t_1)=f(t_2)$$

is true for all $t_1,t_2$ because that's just what functions do; taking an input and giving out an output. For this
$$t_1=t_2 \iff f(t_1)=f(t_2)$$
to be true for all $t_1,t_2$, the function $f$ has to be injective. So when I'm doing my operations on my equations, I can only use the $ \iff $ arrow when I am applying an injective function on both sides of the equations. A simple example would be
$$
x=2 \iff x+x=2+x.
$$
Here I used the injective function $f:t\mapsto t+x$ on both sides of the equation. And because I used this injective function on both sides of the equation I know that the sentence
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb R: (x=2 \iff x+x=2+x)
$$
is true.

Are all these thoughts correct?

Comment: Seems good to me. Did you have a specific question? Perhaps you might want to go down the logical rabbithole of why $t\mapsto t+x$ is injective

Comment: @FShrike my question was, if all of this is really correct  the intuitive answer why $ f:t \mapsto t+x $ is injective, would be that when you plot the function $f$ you get a straight line with the zero of the function being at $t=-x$ and with y-intercept being at $y=t$ .

Comment: @FShrike is the stuff I said about the "intuitive answer" correct?

Comment: The intuition is correct, yes. Formally, if you want to break it down into all the logical sub-pieces, you’d need to use some axioms of real numbers!

Comment: @FShrike I wrote something wrong in my previous comment: my question was, if all of this is really correct  the intuitive answer why $ f:t↦f(t)=t+x $ is injective, would be that when you plot the function $f$ you get a straight line with the zero of the function being at $t=−x$ and with y-intercept being at $y=x$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear and correct!

> The squaring of the equation $ x=2 $ is actually me using the function $h:t\mapsto t^2$ on both sides of $x=2$.
>
> And I know that $x=2 \Rightarrow x^2=4$ is true for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$ because $t_1=t_2 \Rightarrow f(t_1)=f(t_2)$ is true for all $t_1$ and $t_2$.

You know that $(x=2 \Rightarrow x^2=4)$ is true for every $x$ in $\mathbb R$ because

1. for every $t_1$ and $t_2,\:[t_1=t_2 \Rightarrow h(t_1)=h(t_2)]$ is true $\quad$

*and*

2. $h(t)=t^2\Rightarrow h(2)=4.$

Or, simply:  you know that $(x=2 \Rightarrow x^2=4)$ is true for every $x$ in $\mathbb R$ because you know about substitution and that $2^2=4.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. Another example, which is closer yours ($x\mapsto x^2$) is the proposition$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):x^3=8\iff x=2.$$This equivalence follows from the injectivity of$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\x&\mapsto&x^3.\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer. I think you meant to write $$\forall x \in \mathbb R: (x^3=8 \iff x=2). $$ So you put the parentheses at the wrong place, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: This is my way of putting the parenthesis. It's just a matter of convention.

Comment: Ahhh okay I see, sorry!